# Hibernate QueryException - Not all named parameters have been set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've updated my project from Spring Boot 1.3.5 to 1.4.0 (Release) but still stuck on Hibernate 4.3.11.Final. Building and Running the Application works fine, but i'm facing some issues when running my integration-tests.

When my test tries to query for a permission ...

Service:

```
SomePermission permission = permissionRepository.findOne(SomePermission.class, somePermissionId);
```

Repository:

```
@Query("SELECT permission\n" +
        "FROM Permission permission\n" +
        "WHERE TYPE(permission) = :clazz\n" +
        "AND permission.id = :id")
<T extends Permission> T findOne(@Param("clazz") Class<T> cls, @Param("id") long id);
```

... Hibernate returns following Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [clazz] [SELECT permission FROM Permission permission WHERE TYPE(permission) = :clazz AND permission.id = :id]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:524) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:206) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
... 120 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [clazz] [SELECT permission FROM Permission permission WHERE TYPE(permission) = :clazz AND permission.id = :id]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:401) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:385) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:495) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
... 134 common frames omitted
```

Does anybody know why this happens? I've debugged these tests, and both parameters are set...

thx

Comment: Remove the "\n" in your query it is not needed. i am not sur if it will be part of the parameter name

Comment: I suppose `Hibernate` doesn't know how to handle parameters with type `Class`

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24636654/838853

Comment: @Jens Replacing "\n" with spaces didn't help, as said if i run the application normally - everything works fine - its just about the IntegrationTests. I've seen that answer and tried, sadly it didn't help.